# File-like wrapper for Python logging

Tags: python, logging

I would like to build an adaptor object which behaves like a (text) file (opened for output) and forwards each complete line given to it to standard Python logging. Which logger to use and which level to be assigned to lines logged should be specified in the ctor.

Suggestions? Code? Caveats?

Comment: Suggestion: Post the code you tried.  Code: A subclass of `file`.  Caveats: Post the code you tried and we'll comment on it.

Comment: Actually it doesn't need to be a subclass, but it does need to implement the common `file`-like methods (good ol' duck typing).

Comment: Actually, since it's just adding a simple feature to `write`, it should probably be a subclass of `file`.  Saves a lot of coding.

Comment: There's not a lot of coding needed. See my answer.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already done this, see [my post about it](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-treat-logger-like-output-stream.html).

**Update:** It could be a subclass of `file`, but it doesn't especially support other file operations, so there's no particular need for it to be a `file` subclass.

**Further update:** It's up to the OP to adapt the approach in my post - you can subclass `file` if you like, handle buffering, etc. - whatever you need, it doesn't seem like a lot of work either way.

Comment: Why isn't it a subclass of `file`?

Comment: There's no point in making it a subclass of `file`. None of the inherited methods (e.g. `seek()`) will work with a logger, nor can they reasonably be made to do so. Also, the object does not represent a file.

Comment: What about `__enter__`, `__exit__`, `tell()`?  There seem to be a lot of methods which *could* be supported?  Why exclude them?

Comment: The nasty details I need is not so much logging specific, it is the requirement to log _each_ and _only_ **lines**. Is there something inside `file` which can be reused for this? I.e. when `write` gets a buffer with containing newlines, multiple calls to the logger shall happen, and if there is no terminating newline, data should only be buffered and send later.

Comment: What on Earth is `file`'s `tell()` method supposed to do with a logger object?